# Code First - adding to related "tables" in the model?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first, domain-driven-design

I have something like this

```
public class Adult
{
    public int AdultId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual IEnumerable<NicknamedKid> NicknamedKids { get; set; }
}

public class Child
{
    public int ChildId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class NicknamedKid 
{
    public int AdultId { get; set; }
    public int ChildId { get; set; } 
    public string Nickname { get; set; }
}
```

My question is, if I want to create and add a new `NicknamedKid` to an Adult, would I put the method to add the `NicknamedKid` on the `Adult` class, or some `AdultRepository` class? And, if I add it to the `Adult` class, does that mean that class would have to know the `Repository` class to add it?

I guess that I am confused as to how much the Model should know about the Data layer. I am thinking the Model should be able to handle its own layer, and not know about any `Repository` or `DbContext`, but I assume that's not advisable (or possible)?

Comment: Found this, which seems useful http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/207820/The-Repository-Pattern-with-EF-code-first-Dependen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I blame Microsoft. That's generally a safe stance, anyways, but particularly here, they've really mangled the terminology. You have a framework called MVC, which obviously enough is modeled after the pattern of MVC, and they give you folders in your project called "Models", "Views", and "Controllers", appropriately enough. Where they screwed up is in creating sample projects where they fill the "Models" folder with *entities*, which are *not* models.

If you come from another MVC framework, like Ruby on Rails or Django, you're used to the concept of a model that is persisted and *also* is the repository for that persisted data. Microsoft, however, did not go this direction with MVC, instead you get an entity, with no guidance on what is or how to set up your *model*. The natural assumption is that the entity, then, is the model, which, as it did in your case, only serves to confuse.

So what's an entity? It's essentially just a DTO, a Data Transfer Object. It's a class representation of a database table that serves merely as some place for Entity Framework to stuff the data it retrieves. Your "model" from the MVC pattern, actually ends up in practice being an amalgamation of your repositories/services (the DAL) and your view models, which are actually closer to the concept of a model on their own than the entity.

To answer your question, then, no, `Adult` should not be responsible for adding a `NicknamedKid`, nor should it have any reference to Entity Framework or any repository. It should hold only the data that is persisted and any application logic necessary for persistence.

Also, as long as we're here, `NicknamedKid` should not have a reference to `Adult`, regardless, nor should Adult know about `NicknamedKid`. `Adult` references `Child`, and even though you didn't set it up this way (yet), `NicknamedKid` is really just a subclass of `Child`. You've essentially just manually implemented TPT (table per type) inheritance between `Child` and `NicknamedKid` without actually having one inherit from the other. `Nickname` is really just a property of a specific type of `Child` (namely, one that has a nickname. Regardless, though, you should never have an entity that has a foreign to two other entities that already have foreign keys to each other. If you need to get at `NicknamedKid` from `Adult`, you can do that through `Child`. There's no need for a separate relationship.

Comment: The reason I made it this way is because one `Adult` might give a `Child` some nickname but another `Adult` might give the same `Child` a different nickname.

Comment: Also, with `Adult` being just be a DTO object, where would  I put the methods for `Adult` (that do not relate to the data layer)?

Comment: Oh I see. Well, sorry, then. That's just about the only use case where you would have to do it that way. As for your second comment, what kind of methods are you talking about?

Comment: Actually I am having trouble finding an example that wouldn't be data related and thus able to be put on the services for the entity, since the methods are just manipulating data. I have some utility methods that shouldn't be on the classes right now though, that I will have to refactor.